# VS Code code folding of Python code in Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking to fold code in Jupyter Notebook cells.

Note this is different from folding the whole cell or the whole output.

This illustrates the feature well (it's a Gif): [image]

Is there any way to achieve this in VS Code?

Answer (score -2):

you can try to do this .......
[image]

Comment: The original question is not about collapsing entire cells, which this answer addresses. But this answer helped me. I didn't know this was possible.